# why does mysql_fetch_array() expect parameter 1 to be resource? why isn't parameter 1 resource?

Tags: php

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 19

```
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }


 mysql_select_db("schedule", $con);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM classes LIMIT 0,50\n";

 mysql_query($sql);

 IF (!$sql) {
   ECHO 'broken';
 };

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH))
   {
   echo $row['language'] . " " . $row['level'];
   echo "<br />";
   }

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

why?  the query works in phpmyadmin

Comment: It's still a string. You didn't issue a database query (`mysql_query`) at this point.

Comment: I did, I accidentally copypasted from an older version of the file in another directory.  fixed the OP.

Comment: Doesn't change much. `$sql` still a string, you didn't reassign the result handle. -- While you're confused about mysql usage, [look into PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) rather. Less cumbersome, in particular with prepared statements (usually more secure as by-product).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter to mysql_fetch_array() function is your SQL statement **string**. This is what your warning say. You should first use 
    $res = mysql_query($sql); 
and pass $res as parameter to mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 1):

The input to mysql_fetch_Array is a resource, which is also the returned value from mysql_query. If you pass the value $sql to mysql_query(), it will not modify the parameter since it is passed by value. You have to assign the return value to another variable, which will be the desired resource.

```
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

And then, pass the result parameter to mysql_fetch_array :

```
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)
```

Another important note: As you might see in all the related threads, read the red box in the [php.net](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) for these functions.

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
> extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
> related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
> include:
>
> mysqli_query() PDO::query()

Comment: ^ this is a good answer with the right warnings embedded. As in... don't use mysql_* anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change:  mysql_query($sql);
To: `$sql =  mysql_query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

Cited from PHP.net about `mysql_query()`:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

In your case the resource is returned, but you've forgotten to assign it to anything.

Change `mysql_query($sql)` to `$resource = mysql_query($sql)`.

Full documentation right here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php